# Bash- how to handle pipeline with multiple argument and -o pipeline enable

Tags: bash, pipeline

So I have this pipeline with set -o pipefail in the top of script.

```
 local numbr_match
    numbr_match=$(ls -t1 logs/repologs | grep "$name" | wc --lines)
 if [ ! -z "${numbr_match}" ] && [ "${numbr_match}" -le 
   "$logrot_keep"];then
    echo "Found $numbr_match backups matching '$name', don't need to 
     remove until we have more than $logrot_keep"
 else
```

If ls -t1 are not finding anything therefore grep fails I belive whole pipeline fails with pipefail. Whats the best solution to use to come around this?

Comment: What do you get if you change the `ls` command to false instead?

Comment: Hm, can u elaborate? Im kinda beginner

Comment: Change to `numbr_match=$(false | grep "$name" | wc --lines)`.  Does it "fail" like you think it does?

Comment: Not right now. I want the script to keep going even if no matches was found under logs/repologs

Comment: I unfortunately can't reproduce the problem in my end. Even if `ls` produces errors, I still get `0`, and not an empty string. And that implies I enabled `pipefail`.

Comment: Why not turn off the pipefail for this command (`set +o pipefail`)?

Comment: I think ls -t1 produce error when trying to find logs but cant find any, therefore the pipeline fails.  @konsolebox 

Thanks for the tips I will try that

Comment: It's @Jens's suggestion.  While this obviously can be bypassed by disabling it, I'd rather know first why it's needed.  Like I said on my end even if `ls` fails, the value is still 0.

Comment: "If ls -t1 are not finding anything I belive whole pipeline fails with pipefail." How can this exactly be reproduced? Maybe you're misperceiving an error message coming from `ls` like for because of an existent directory for a pipeline "failure" - which could mean the command substitution not returning `0` or the `wc` not being able to send a string at all because the pipeline failed. This needs clarification.

Comment: I think as user1934428 wrote. It's probably the error msg from grep failing because if /repologs/ are empty it wont get any input. But how could I bypass this and still using -o pipefail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the ls.

Even if logs/repologs is an empty directory, `ls` would still set exit status 0. If log/repologs does not exist, `ls` sets exit code 2. You could catch the latter by guarding the whole pipe with a `[[ -d logs/repologs ]] && ...`

The main problem is the grep:

If the directory is empty, `grep` does not get any input, and therefore your pipefail fires. You could avoid this by doing a

```
ls -a logs/repologs
```

but this produces at least two additional entries (`.` and `..`) and your `wc` count would be off by 2. It would also include other hidden entries in the directories.

However, what's the purpose of the whole statement? If you just want to count the number of non-hidden entries in the directory, your method is unreliable anyway, for if you have a file where the name contains an embedded newline character, it would be counted as two entries.

A more reasonable approach would be to load all the files into an array and take the length of the array:

```
shopt -s nullglob
files=(logs/repologs/*"$name"*)
echo Number of non-hidden entries : ${#files[*]}
```

**UPDATE**:

For completeness: My solution is a bit different to yours in the following respect:

Assume that you would set

```
name=foo.bar
```

In your solution, entries `fooxbar` and `fooybar` would be counted as well, while in my solution, only a literal `foo.bar` would be counted. The same applies to other characters which have a special meaning inside a simple regular expression.

Comment: I think he wants: `logs/repologs/*"$name"*`.

Comment: Ah, right. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yes you are probably right that the grep is the one failing when not finding any from the ls. The purpose of this pipe is to list all from /repologs and afterwards use them in a if statement to logrotate . I will update the ticket

Comment: @user8801226: Be careful to update your quesiton in a way that existing answers (i.e. mine) become invalid.

Comment: No problem, your answer are still valid.

Comment: _"My solution is a bit different to yours"_ : a `newline` in a filename would also be wrongly counted with `grep`

Comment: I have updated the question now for some more clarification

Comment: Actually I was needed to set local numbr_match=0 AND change to ls -a instead of ls -tl for it even to work. Do you know why?

Comment: `ls -a` sorts alphabetically, outputs only the filenames, and includes **all** hidden entries, even `.` and `..`. I can't think of a reason why you want this. Actually, you should not use `ls` at all. If you want the hidden entries, you can also adapt my solution to show them, but it is better if you are asking a new question on those topics instead of discussing it in comments.